# How can I edit my php file with style.css?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have made a website thats allows my visitors to upload pictures and view them on a other link. Here is mijn website http://sixpi.nl/dev And here is my code.
My question is how can I make the media.php page look nice. And how can I edit it with CSS? I want the media.php look like this (http://pexels.com) thank you.

**This is my HTML file called index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>

<a href="media.php">Kijk alle media!</a>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
<img id="preview" alt="your image" width="100" height="100" />
<form action="upload.php" method="post" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select file to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"  onchange="document.getElementById('preview').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])">
    <button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit">Upload File</button>

 </form>
 </body>
 </head>
 </html>
```

**This is my upload script called upload.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>

<a href="media.php">Kijk alle media!</a>

<img id="preview" alt="your image" width="100" height="100" />


<form action="upload.php" method="post" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select file to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"  onchange="document.getElementById('preview').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])">
    <button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit">Upload File</button>
 </form>

 </body>
 </head>
 </html>
```

**This is my media link alle the uploaded images are visible called media.php**

```
<?php
     $files = glob("upload/*.*");
     for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)
      {
        $image = $files[$i];
        $supported_file = array(
                'gif',
                'jpg',
                'jpeg',
                'png'
         );

         $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
         if (in_array($ext, $supported_file)) {
             echo $image ."<br />";
             echo '<img src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image" width="600" height="480" />'."<br /><br />";
            } else {
                continue;
            }
          }

       ?>
```

Comment: You are echoing HTML in PHP. Styling that is no different than styling HTML.

Comment: But how can I give a style to a php element? Giving the php element a id? If it is, how can I do it?

Comment: That depends entirely on what you mean by "a php element".

Comment: My media.php file shows every image in the upload folder. But I want the image look organized and clean like this website (http://pexels.com) How can I do it?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "PHP element". A PHP script generates HTML, which can be styled as usual. Not sure what else to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply echo entire html code and you can use style for it. Here is and example :

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
        {
            ?>
<div class="myClass"></div>
        <?php
        }
?>
```

Here you can style the class called myClass in your css.

If you don't want to use looping then this would be useful to you.

```
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

Remember php can echo any html in double quotes. Hope this helps :)